# Detecting broken Image functions created in an Array Formula in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gK3nlf4SY0y1tN1Cz_CMI4oZDncziQxWfuD-3rMa6Cw

In Column A there are random numbers between 100 and 300.

In Column B there is an ARRAYFORMULA that pulls images from a directory: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE("https://www.roadpics.net/Serie38/Images/photo" & B2:B25 & ".jpg"))`

**The challenge is to detect in Column C which cells in Column B have images.** A simple True/False will suffice.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just check the url instead?

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping for a solution to detect images in cells regardless of origin (manually placed, in-cell formula, array formula...) but it seems that is not possible under the current constraints of Google Drive.

So I took @TheMaster's advice and instead I check the URL and show an image only if the URL is valid. If not, I throw a NA error to allow me to detect and take the appropriate action (in my case, attempt another image URL).

Here's my code:

```js
function VALIDATEURL(_link) {
  if (_link.map) { //Is true if _link is an array
    return _link.map(VALIDATEURL); //Recurse over array
  } else { //Not an array
    var code = 0; //Sets temp code
    if (/^http/i.test(_link)) {
      try {
        code = UrlFetchApp.fetch(_link).getResponseCode();
      } catch (e) {}
    }
    return code === 200; //If response code is 200, return true, else false
  }
}
```

I then call the custom function with the following formula (URLs are in Column D):

```
=IF(
  VALIDATEURL(D2),
  IMAGE(D2),
  NA()
)
```

Hope that helps someone with a similar issue.